# Keyboard won't dismiss?

Tags: react-native

I have a notes input that is multilined. Currently when I press return it goes to the next line and when I tap on a part of the screen that isn't a keyboard nothing happens. So it's just stuck right now and i have to reload the app. I have tried the keyboard dismissal and it still isn't working. This is a child component so maybe that is the issue?

My code:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss()}> //also tried () => Keyboard.dismiss()
        <Modal transparent animationType='fade' visible={this.props.createHomeworkModalVisible}>
          <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
            <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
              <Formik
                initialValues={{
                  assignmentName: '',
                  dueDate: null,
                  notes: '',
                  pictures: []
                }}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}
                onSubmit={(values) => {
                  console.log(values);
                }}
              >
                {formikProps => (
                  <View>
                      <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
                        <TextInput
                          placeholder={'Add notes'}
                          placeholderTextColor='#cdd2c9'
                          value={formikProps.values.notes}
                          multiline
                          style={styles.notesInput}
                          onChangeText={formikProps.handleChange('notes')}
                          onBlur={formikProps.handleBlur('notes')}
                        />
                      </View>
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to add your Touchable inside Modal. onPress should be onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} or onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like,

```
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native'

<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
    <View>
                      <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
                        <TextInput
                          placeholder={'Add notes'}
                          placeholderTextColor='#cdd2c9'
                          value={formikProps.values.notes}
                          multiline
                          style={styles.notesInput}
                          onChangeText={formikProps.handleChange('notes')}
                          onBlur={formikProps.handleBlur('notes')}
                        />
                      </View>
                  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

import `Keyboard` from 'react-native'

Call this function : `Keyboard.dismiss()`